# Javascript WebSocket to Java server taking long time to connect every other one, ~6s

Tags: javascript, java, asynchronous, web, websocket

When I visit the website using the **ip address**, everything goes rapid fast.

When **I use** the **domain** to navigate, every other result takes long time for the websocket to complete.

Sometimes, it is instant, sometimes it takes **6 seconds**.

I am on **JEE 7** using **websocket endpoint**.

What could be wrong here? It's been like this for a long time.

Could my router be involved here? I am forwarding port 80 traffic.

Note, I am **not** currently on **https**, because it's just for a demo and there is no time to set that up. Could that me the reason? If so, is there a **way around** that?

Comment: I think you should check your DNS name resolution... If by "domain" you meant "host name(with domain)"....

Comment: This sounds like your DNS entry for your host might have multiple IP addresses in it for your host and one of those is bad so it has to wait for that one to fail before it tries the other one.  Which one it picks the first time would be random so sometimes it would get he good one, sometimes the bad one first.

Comment: hmm multiple? i have one for www.domain.com and domain.com .. both point to the same IP .. nothing else ...